# Php, Guzzle, Schema validation failed but working in curl

Tags: php, guzzle

I'm in the process of convert from cURL to Guzzle, and got most of it working.
GET requests working great etc.

My problem is the POST request, getting Schema validation errors.
It works in curl, so I'm a bit confused... well, a lot.

```
Client error: `POST https://restapi.e-conomic.com/customers` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"message":"Schema validation failed.","errorCode":"E00500"
```

I hope one of you can tell me, if I did something wrong in the convert? Maybe my arrays needs to be formatted in another way.

**This is my old working "cURL code":**

```
$data = array(
'name' => 'Test User',
'address' => 'Road 123',
'email' => 'morten@domain.com',
'zip' => '9000',
'city' => 'City',
'country' => 'Danmark',
'corporateIdentificationNumber' => '12345678',
'customerGroup' => array(
    'customerGroupNumber' => 1
),
'currency' => 'DKK',
'paymentTerms' => array(
    'paymentTermsNumber' => 1
),
'vatZone' => array(
    'vatZoneNumber' => 1
)
);

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://restapi.e-conomic.com/customers',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'X-AppSecretToken:[removed]',
        'X-AgreementGrantToken:[removed]',
        'Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8'
    ),
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data)
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
```

**This is my new "guzzle code", that is causing me problems:**

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

$headers = [
    'X-AppSecretToken' => '[removed]',
    'X-AgreementGrantToken' => '[removed]',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    'debug' => false
];

$form_params = [
    'name' => 'Test User',
    'address' => 'Road 123',
    'email' => 'test@email.dk',
    'zip' => '9000',
    'city' => 'City',
    'country' => 'Danmark',
    'corporateIdentificationNumber' => '12345678',
    'customerGroup' => [
        'customerGroupNumber' => 1
    ],
    'currency' => 'DKK',
    'paymentTerms' => [
        'paymentTermsNumber' => 1
    ],
    'vatZone' => [
        'vatZoneNumber' => 1
    ]
];

$response = $client->post('https://restapi.e-conomic.com/customers', [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'form_params' => $form_params
]);
```

I tried to use the "body" parameter, as stated in the Guzzle documentation, but received this error:

```
Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request.
```

I'm not sure what to do and really hope, that one of you guys will tell me what i'm doing wrong.

https://restapi.e-conomic.com/schema/customers.post.schema.json#_ga=2.167601086.1488491524.1500877149-796726383.1499933074

https://restdocs.e-conomic.com/#post-customers

Answer (score 0):

I had to post the quest as json:

```
$response = $client->post('https://restapi.e-conomic.com/customers', [
    'headers' => $headers,
    'json' => $form_params
]);
```